# How to refresh DataTable with server side processing and Scroller extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was tried to use these approaches:

1. Using api().draw(false) function, but it resets scroll offset.
2. Using api().ajax.reload(null, false). It resets scroll offset too.
3. Using dataTable._fnDraw() function. It doesn't work too. There is a bug when you are trying a bit scroll and after _fnDraw() call it scrolls to previous position. When you are scrolling a lot - it works well.

My TypeScript code:

```js
var dataTableOptions = {
  serverSide: true,
  ordering: true,
  searching: true,
  columns: [
    { "data": "id" },
    { "data": "workflowId" },
    { "data": "discovery" },
    { "data": "title" },
    { "data": "createdBy" },
    { "data": "createDate" },
    { "data": "status" }
  ],
  ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
    // server side service call
  },
  dom: 'rtiS',
  scrollY: 400,
  scroller: {
    rowHeight: 35,
    loadingIndicator: true
  },
  initComplete: function () {
    
    forceRefresh = _.throttle(() => {
      //this.api().ajax.reload(false);
      this._fnDraw();
    }, 1000);
  
    setInterval(() => {
      forceRefresh();
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any other way as get `scrollTop` of scroller before ajax call and after table refresh (`api().ajax.reload`) assign it again. It's works for me.

Comment: How did you get/set scrollTop ? Is there a method on the table API or did you use properties from a DOM element ?

Comment: I used properties from a DOM

Answer (score 0):

Datatable automatically refresh (with updated data) on server side operation, no need to force refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTableOptions = {
      serverSide: true,
      ordering: true,
      searching: true,
      columns: [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "workflowId" },
        { "data": "discovery" },
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "createdBy" },
        { "data": "createDate" },
        { "data": "status" }
      ],
      ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
        // server side service call
      },
      dom: "frtiS",
      scrollY: 400,
      deferRender: true,
      scroller: {
        rowHeight: 35,
        loadingIndicator: true
      }
    }
```

A live example can be found [here](http://coderexample.com/datatable-scroller-server-side/)

Comment: Yes, but it requires user interaction. I would like to have as real time data, no any user interaction here. Just refreshing datatable in interval.